# importXML xpath to google sheets returns #N/A

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets-formula, google-search

Under the following span class I am looking to extract the number (416) 123-1234. This number is written after data-number or at the end of the span.

```
<span class="_Xbe _ZWk kno-fv"> ## The Unique ID is _Xbe _ZWk kno-fv
      <a class="fl r-idASUKPhOV34" href="#" data-number="+14161231234" data-pstn-
      -call-url="" title="Call via Hangouts" jsaction="r.oVdbr2mIpA8" 
      data-rtid="idASUKPhOV34" jsl="$t t-6xg4lalHw8M;$x 0;" data-ved="0ahUKEwiDtKTG-snZAhUDzIMKHcntCfAQkAgImAEoADAU">(416) 123-1234</a></span>
```

The problem comes from the XPATH, I am not specifying the right xpath, I tried to copy xpath from the source code and it returned #N/A. My best guess is the following xpath with importxml, though it still returns #N/A.

```
 =IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A10,"//span[@class='_Xbe _ZWk kno-fv']/a/@href")
```

How can I write XPATH to extract the number in either form?

Comment: Are you sure that class name is static? Try `//a[@title="Call via Hangouts"]/@href`

Comment: Thanks! The span class is static based on 10 different google search. But I like your method better! When I tried the xpath //a[@title="Call via Hangouts"]/@href it returns #ERROR in the parsing formula.